# perl script to compare a file having 1 column with another file having many columns

Tags: file, compare

Hi I have a file with this kind of data:

file_one.txt

```
test1  
test2  
test3  
test4  
test5  
test6  
test7  
test8
```

and I want to compare that file with a file having this format

```
file_two.txt

big1("\t")big2("\t")big3  
test1("\t")test3("\t")test7  
test2("\t")test6("\t")test8  
test4("\t")test1("\t")test1
```

What I want as an output is a file with this format

```
output_file.txt

test1("\t")big1("\t")big2("\t")big3  
test2("\t")big1     
test3("\t")big2  
test4("\t")big1  
test5
test6("\t")big2  
test7("\t")big3  
test8("\t")big3
```

where ("\t") stands for tab I just could not place tab in between the elements
So in other words the header of file_two I want it as an extra column in any time an element of file two is in common with an element in column one. Whenever an element from column one is not found in column two I want just this element printed.

Can you please help me with this problem?